# I am using weighted average to get the data but my total score is coming 0

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I have data from JSON and using weighted to total and show the top 3 scored countries. I am given the option to use to sort and arrange their preference based on that score1*pref1 + score2*pref2+score3*pref3 ... feature but my total score is coming as 0 in all cases.

When I am using inputs instead of sort it is working as expected.
https://codepen.io/kunalvijan/pen/eYxVZwM

But after moving it to sort I am getting a total score always 0. Any help!

Attaching the code for ref.

```js
var sortable = new Sortable(document.getElementById('sortableList'), {
      animation: 150,
      onUpdate: function (evt) {
        // Automatically assign priorities based on the new order
        var items = evt.from.children;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          var item = items[i];
          item.dataset.priority = i + 1;
        }
      }
    });

    function calculateAndDisplay() {
      var userPreferences = {};

      // Collect priorities from the sorted list
      var items = document.getElementById('sortableList').children;
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        userPreferences[item.dataset.id] = parseInt(item.dataset.priority);
      }

      console.log("User Preferences: ", userPreferences);

      var countriesData = [
        {
          "Country": "USA",
          "Employment Rate": 5.10,
          "University Rankings": 37.78,
          "Tuition Fees": 9.30,
          "PR and Settlement Opportunities": 6.06,
          "Graduate Pay Scales": 6.63,
          "Spouse Work Rights": 3.85,
          "Cost of Living": 7.58,
          "Cultural Fit": 5.41,
          "Safety and Security": 3.49,
          "Quality of Life": 4.65 
        },
        {
          "Country": "UK",
          "Employment Rate": 5.20,
          "University Rankings": 12.22,
          "Tuition Fees": 8.63,
          "PR and Settlement Opportunities": 4.55,
          "Graduate Pay Scales": 5.42,
          "Spouse Work Rights": 6.41,
          "Cost of Living": 6.72,
          "Cultural Fit": 5.41,
          "Safety and Security": 4.65,
          "Quality of Life": 4.65
        }
      ];

      var totalScores = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < countriesData.length; i++) {
        var countryData = countriesData[i];
        var totalScore = 0;

        for (var attribute in userPreferences) {
          if (countryData.hasOwnProperty(attribute)) {
            var attributeWeight = countryData[attribute] * userPreferences[attribute];
            totalScore += attributeWeight;
          }
        }

        console.log(countryData);

        totalScores.push({ "Country": countryData.Country, "TotalScore": totalScore });
      }

      totalScores.sort((a, b) => b.TotalScore - a.TotalScore);

      console.log("Sorted Total Scores: ", totalScores);

      // Display the results on the same page
      var resultsContainer = document.getElementById("resultsContainer");
      resultsContainer.innerHTML = "<h2>Top 3 Results</h2>";

      // Display the top 3 countries
      for (var j = 0; j < Math.min(3, totalScores.length); j++) {
        resultsContainer.innerHTML += "<p>" + totalScores[j].Country + " - Total Score: " + totalScores[j].TotalScore.toFixed(2) + "</p>";
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.14.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<div id="sortableList">
    <div data-id="employmentRate">Employment Rate</div>
    <div data-id="universityRankings">University Rankings</div>
    <div data-id="tuitionFees">Tuition Fees</div>
    <div data-id="prOpportunities">PR and Settlement Opportunities</div>
    <div data-id="graduatePayScales">Graduate Pay Scales</div>
    <div data-id="spouseWorkRights">Spouse Work Rights</div>
    <div data-id="costOfLiving">Cost of Living</div>
    <div data-id="culturalFit">Cultural Fit</div>
    <div data-id="safetyAndSecurity">Safety and Security</div>
    <div data-id="qualityOfLife">Quality of Life</div>
  </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="calculateAndDisplay()">Submit</button>

  <div id="resultsContainer"></div>
```

Comment: `userPreferences` has no attributes so this code does nothing: `for (var attribute in userPreferences) ...`. What were you expecting?

Comment: UserPerference is getting order in object
User Preferences: {
    "employmentRate": 1,
    "universityRankings": 2,
    "tuitionFees": 3,
    "prOpportunities": 4,
    "qualityOfLife": 5,
    "graduatePayScales": 6,
    "spouseWorkRights": 7,
    "costOfLiving": 8,
    "culturalFit": 9,
    "safetyAndSecurity": 10
}

Comment: @kmoser i have it working here.. https://codepen.io/kunalvijan/pen/eYxVZwM but it has input instead of sorting.. i need sorting

Comment: @kmoser `for (let attribute of userPreferences)`, not `for (var ... in ...)`. Dont use `var` in new code (use `let` for mutable and `const` for immutable variables), and for-in [has a whole bunch of footnotes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#array_iteration_and_for...in) that ends in "It is better to use a for loop with a numeric index, `Array.prototype.forEach()`, or the `for...of` loop".

Comment: @kmoser it didn't work .. will you able to update the code n make it working?